# Comparar dos strings jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hola tengo el siguente problema quiero ocultar todos los items que no contengan el mismo data title tal como se escribio en el input

```
$(document).on('click', '#submitsearch', function(){
        var query = $('#search').val().trim();
        console.log(query);
        var hijos = $('#insert').children()
        hijos.each(function(query){
              $(this).hide()
              var title = $(this).data('title').trim()
              // console.log(title)
              console.log(query === title)
              if (query === title){
                 $(this).show()
              }
        })
});
```

me esta retornando falso en todos los casos aunque copie y pegue exactamente el mismo data-title

Comment: que te muestra el console log de cada variable?

Comment: ejemplo:

`console.log(query) = Fina ensalada de fiesta
console.log(title) = Fina ensalada de fiesta
console.log(query === title) = False`

Comment: solo as un `if(query.toUpperCase() === title.toUpperCase()){this.show()}`

Comment: @Bryro me estaria ocultado el que se tendria que mostrar, y todos los demas se dejan visibles

Comment: ¿Has mirado si alguno de los console.logs tiene algún espacio por delante o por detrás?, porque sino no debería devolverte false, hay una diferencia fijo.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta usar este código sustituyendo **'==='** por **'=='**

```
$(document).on('click', '#submitsearch', function(){
        var query = $('#search').val().trim();
        console.log(query);
        var hijos = $('#insert').children()
        hijos.each(function(query){
              $(this).hide()
              var title = $(this).data('title').trim()
              // console.log(title)
              console.log(query == title)
              if (query == title){
                 $(this).show()
              }
        }) });
```

Comment: me devuelve false en todos los casos

Answer (score 0):

En el `each` estas pasando como parámetro `query`, y ya lo habías declarado arriba, solo borra ese parámetro.
Quedaría así:

```
$(document).on('click', '#submitsearch', function(){
        var query = $('#search').val().trim();
        console.log(query);
        var hijos = $('#insert').children()
        hijos.each(function(){
              $(this).hide()
              var title = $(this).data('title').trim()
              // console.log(title)
              console.log(query === title)
              if (query === title){
                 $(this).show()
              }
        })
});
```

Comment: estaria funcionando el problema es que esta ocultado el que se tendria que mostrar